# Top left sprites disappear and I don't know how to fix it. PyGame Randomly generated sprite maze

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make a maze game, and the maze is randomly generated using sprites, however, the top-left cell is always empty and I do not know how to fix this without breaking the code for removing certain cells depending on the direction of which the computer takes. If anyone knows how to fix this please help.

Code:

```
import pygame, random,time
pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 810
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 810
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))


class Cell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = 80
        self.N = True
        self.E = True
        self.S = True
        self.W = True
        self.image = pygame.Surface([80, 80])
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # self.rect.x = x
        # self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        if self.N:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+1, self.size, 1])
        if self.W:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+1, 1, self.size])
        if self.S:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+self.size+1, self.size,1])
        if self.E:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+self.size+1, self.y+1, 1, self.size+1])

    def clear_wall(self, side):
        if side.lower() == "west":
            self.W = False
        elif side.lower() == "east":
            self.E = False
        elif side.lower() == "north":
            self.N = False
        elif side.lower() == "south":
            self.S = False


def find_cell(cells, current, direction):
    for c in cells:
        if direction == "east":
            if c.x == current.x + 80 and c.y == current.y:
                return c  # found the correct cell, so return it
        if direction == "west":
            if c.x == current.x - 80 and c.y == current.y:
                return c
        if direction == "south":
            if c.x == current.x and c.y == current.y + 80:
                return c
        if direction == "north":
            if c.x == current.x and c.y == current.y - 80:
                return c


def getOppositeDir(direction):
    if direction.lower() == "east":
        return "west"
    elif direction.lower() == "west":
        return "east"
    elif direction.lower() == "north":
        return "south"
    elif direction.lower() == "south":
        return "north"


def generate_maze(cells):
    current = cells.sprites()[random.randint(0, 79)] # starting point
    # Set current cell to initial starting point
    direction = "south"
    for x in range(800):
        joining_cell = find_cell(cells, current, direction)
        current.clear_wall(direction)
        try:
            joining_cell.clear_wall(getOppositeDir(direction))
            current = joining_cell  # move to the new current cell
            direction = random.choice(["north", "east", "south", "west"])
        except:
            pass


def Main():
    cells = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            cells.add(Cell(y * 80, x * 80))
    generate_maze(cells)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    onRun = True
    while onRun:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runOn = False
        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        cells.update()
        cells.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    Main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I think.

The issue was that you didn't position your images, so all the Cells had their white Surface blitting at (0,0), which is why the topleft Cell's never had visible lines.

I fixed that by setting the rect to the location using surface.get_rect(top_left=location)).

But then all the cells were covered, so I reversed the draw and update steps.

IDK, hopefully this is helpful.

```
import pygame, random,time
pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 810
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 810
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))


class Cell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = 80
        self.N = True
        self.E = True
        self.S = True
        self.W = True
        self.image = pygame.Surface([80, 80])
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x,y))
        # self.rect.x = x
        # self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        if self.N:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+1, self.size, 1])
        if self.W:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+1, 1, self.size])
        if self.S:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+1, self.y+self.size+1, self.size,1])
        if self.E:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), [self.x+self.size+1, self.y+1, 1, self.size+1])

    def clear_wall(self, side):
        if side.lower() == "west":
            self.W = False
        elif side.lower() == "east":
            self.E = False
        elif side.lower() == "north":
            self.N = False
        elif side.lower() == "south":
            self.S = False


def find_cell(cells, current, direction):
    for c in cells:
        if direction == "east":
            if c.x == current.x + 80 and c.y == current.y:
                return c  # found the correct cell, so return it
        if direction == "west":
            if c.x == current.x - 80 and c.y == current.y:
                return c
        if direction == "south":
            if c.x == current.x and c.y == current.y + 80:
                return c
        if direction == "north":
            if c.x == current.x and c.y == current.y - 80:
                return c


def getOppositeDir(direction):
    if direction.lower() == "east":
        return "west"
    elif direction.lower() == "west":
        return "east"
    elif direction.lower() == "north":
        return "south"
    elif direction.lower() == "south":
        return "north"


def generate_maze(cells):
    current = cells.sprites()[random.randint(0, 79)] # starting point
    # Set current cell to initial starting point
    direction = "south"
    for x in range(800):
        joining_cell = find_cell(cells, current, direction)
        current.clear_wall(direction)
        try:
            joining_cell.clear_wall(getOppositeDir(direction))
            current = joining_cell  # move to the new current cell
            direction = random.choice(["north", "east", "south", "west"])
        except:
            pass


def main():
    cells = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            print(y*80, x*80)
            cells.add(Cell(y * 80, x * 80))
    generate_maze(cells)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    onRun = True
    while onRun:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                onRun = False
        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        cells.draw(screen)
        cells.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```